# How to deal with negative coefficients in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multicollinearity, regression-coefficients

I have 5 single factor regression models. Each has intuitive (positive) coefficients which is good. If I run multiple logistic regression one of the coefficients turns negative.

If I run stepwise selection, the negative coefficient stays in ... it's not redundant ...

How should I deal with this? Is there a way to enforce positive coefficients?

Comment: Isn't it possible that your independent variable that obtains negative coefficient in multiple-prediction circumstances serves as a suppressor variable?

Comment: possible. But ideally, I want regression with all positive coefficients... any ideas as to recommended approaches?

Comment: What is the problem with a negative coefficient? Why do you think all the coefficients must be positive? It is perfectly valid for a logistic regression model to have negative coefficients, isn't it?

Comment: is counter-intuitive... for example counsuming alchohol should not decrease probability of geting leaver problems..

Comment: then probably you have some multicollinearity in your regressands (there is simply too many of them you want to include), try principal components for instance for "bad habits" and "good habits" or other interpretable results.

Comment: yeah... I tried PCA.. but it's nightmare to interpret intuitivness of the coefficients...

Comment: Give more details about the 5 predictors. Otherwise is hard to help you..

Comment: If the direction of the coefficient seems strange, it's possible its effect is being absorbed by a linear combination of the other predictors in the model. Look at the pairwise associations among the predictors.

Comment: @Dmitrij @user Multicollinearity is unlikely to be the problem.  A change of sign when a new independent variable is introduced is a strong signal of a possible *interaction.*  The next step--which should be done in any event--is to investigate the pairwise interactions.

Comment: If you _want_ to restrict the coefficients to be positive, that's easy to accomplish, e.g., using the log-barrier method (or any off-the-shelf constrained optimization tool). The log-likelihood function for logistic regression is concave, so its restriction to a convex region (the positive orthant) is also concave, meaning there's a unique global maximum.

But I concur with the other commenters: restricting them to be positive isn't necessarily the right thing to do.

Comment: @whuber That's exctly whAT I did. I tested interaction terms (when I could think of valid rationalle). Interaction term get's right coefficient sign but it "invokes" minuses in other variables.... disaster!

Comment: @user Please explain why that's a "disaster"!  Remember, when interactions are present, the coefficients alone are (almost) meaningless: to assess the effective slopes, you need to evaluate the partial derivatives of the response with respect to variates at selected values of the variates.

Comment: @whuber. Thanks. To be honest, I didn't expect individual coefficients to be meaningless when I have interaction terms. THanks for pointing that out.